# Linker script section order

Tags: mips, qemu, linker-scripts

I am using the qemu emulator to emulate a MIPS system. I wrote a very simple boot code and main function. However when I used the following linker script the qemu emulator gave the message "qemu-system-mipsel: Could not load MIPS bios 'bin/img.bin', and no -kernel argument was specified":

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
    .boottext 0xBFC00000 : { obj/startup.o(.text) }
    .text 0xA0000000  : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
    . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
    .stack ALIGN( 16 ) :{ *(.stack) }
    _stacktop = ALIGN(16);
}
```

When I changed the linkerscript to the following script, qemu ran the code perfectly:

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
    .text 0xA0000000  : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
    . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
    .stack ALIGN( 16 ) :{ *(.stack) }
    _stacktop = ALIGN(16);
    .boottext 0xBFC00000 : { obj/startup.o(.text) }
}
```

So, my question is: what is the impact of the order of the sections in the script in the final elf and binary files? Why does qemu runs one but not the other?

Thank you in advance

PS: ran qemu with "qemu-system-mipsel -s -M malta -m 512M -bios bin/img.bin"

Comment: Yes. Very much so.
With correct script:
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 josemar josemar  8368 Nov  4 07:26 img.bin*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 josemar josemar 75960 Nov  4 07:26 img.elf*`

With wrong one:
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 josemar josemar 532676644 Nov  4 07:28 img.bin*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 josemar josemar    133236 Nov  4 07:28 img.elf*`